# Save media files (images) to database instead of the filesystem

Tags: images, database, uploads, filesystem

I have an out-of-the-box installation of WordPress with WooCommerce. I see that uploaded images (e.g. when I create a product) are saved in the filesystem under `wp-content/uploads/`. I would like the images be saved in the database instead. Is that possible?

I am aware about cons on saving media to the database instead of the filesystem.

Comment: Unless you have a very specific need for this which can't be solved by other means, I would advise against it.
While it is possible to store images in the database, there is no way to do this with a standard WordPress installation so you will have to create your own functionality (which is not a trivial thing to do) and you won't be able to use the standard image-related functionalities of WP.

Comment: It will also save load on the database if you just serve them from the filesystem instead. What problem are you trying to solve? Are you hoping to scale this horizontally without having to have a shared filesystem for uploads?

Comment: OK. You might get lucky and find an existing implementation of this, else you're going to have to 1) make a new table with blob storage type for the images 2) work out what you're going to do with image sizes: store them all in the database, or just the raw size, or a smaller selection? 3) change the upload code to store the image in the database, either on upload or after creating the sized versions 4) create a new endpoint to serve images from the database 5) change wp_get_attachment_image_url etc. to generate URLs for this new endpoint.